# Cannot addClass to element inside .done() with jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

**html**

Once the data was typed inside  it will call `autosave2` function to save it via .php. If the new value not different then do nothing.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="autosave2" name="price1" data-oval="500" value="700" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="autosave2" name="price2" data-oval="300" value="500" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="autosave2" name="price3" data-oval="600" value="800" /></td>
</tr>
```

**jquery**

The value from input has sent to .php file and return the result `updated` if no errors. Over here, I check the response if it's = `updated` then addClass `is-valid` to the `<input>` itself. **The problem is it's not update the input as expect.** Despite the same code outside `.done` is working fine. (If I un-comment the other lines below). `console.log(data)` is working just fine as well.

```
        $(".autosave2").on('blur',function(){
            var i_name=$(this).attr('name');
            var i_val=$(this).val();
            var i_oval=$(this).data('oval');
            $.post( "settings_price_limit.php",{name:i_name,val:i_val,oval:i_oval,mode:'default'}, function( data ) {
              console.log(data);    
                  if(data=="update"){
                      $(this).closest('td').find('input.autosave2').addClass('is-valid');
                  }
            });
            //$(this).closest('td').find('input.autosave2').addClass('is-valid');
        });
```

**settings_price_limit.php**

```
echo "updated";
```

Comment: You have to bind the callback to "this" explicitly: `$.post(..., function( data ) { ... }.bind(this));`

Comment: I'm new to jquery, please explain more.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. In JavaScript the value of `this` does not propagate to nested functions automatically (except for arrow functions). The `post`-callback uses a different `this` context as your `onblur`-callback by default, so you have to either bind the `this`-context explicitly to your callback function or save a reference beforehand like `let self = this;` and use that within the post-callback: `$(self).closest('td')...`.

Comment: let self = this;
    $.post( "settings_price_limit.php",{name:i_name,val:i_val,oval:i_oval,mode:'default'}, function( data ) {
      console.log(data); 
       if(data=="update"){
        $(self).closest('td').find('input.autosave2').addClass('is-valid');
       }
    }.bind(this));

Comment: I'm I right? nothing change :(

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/  so I can reproduce the problem on my end.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1a02fLuw/

Comment: I don't know how to return php back to .done().

Comment: You echo `"updated"` but in your JS you check for `"update"`. What does `console.log(data)` log to the console?

Comment: After the process from php. It will echo "updated". console.log(data) also get this one from php as well. That's why I want to check if the response is "updated" then addClass to input.

Comment: Yes but in your javascript you check for `if(data=="update")` ... "update", not "update**d**", so your code will never run.

Comment: It's working!!! What an idiot me. Thank you it's working now :(